# geoip-lite formatting of characters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code, which basically looks up an IP address when a user hits the http://domain.tld/stats/1.gif and uses the geoip-lite library to return lat and long on a raphael map.

```
    var http = require('http'),
    util  = require('util'),
    static = require('node-static'),
    faye = require('faye'),
    url = require('url'),
    geoip = require('geoip-lite');

    function LiveStats(options) {
    if (! (this instanceof arguments.callee)) {
      return new arguments.callee(arguments);
    }

    ...

  } else if (location.pathname == '/stats/1.gif' && request.method == 'GET') {
        var origin;
        response.writeHead(200, {
              'Content-Type': 'image/gif'
        });
        origin = /\/(.*)\.gif/.exec(request.url);
        if (origin) {
        var ip = request.connection.remoteAddress;
        var geo = geoip.lookup(ip);
        console.log(geo);
        self.bayeux.getClient().publish('/stat', {
                 title: 'user'
               , latitude: geo.ll[0]
               , longitude: geo.ll[1]
               , ip: ip
             });
            }
            response.end("OK");
 } else {
        file.serve(request, response);
      }
    });
  });
  return server;
};

module.exports = LiveStats;
```

console.log(geo);

returns for example:

```
{ range: [ 1391911936, 1391915007 ],
  country: 'FR',
  region: 'A9',
  city: 'N?mes',
  ll: [ 43.8333, 4.35 ] }
```

where the city formatting is all wrong, how should i correct this, so that it prints Nîmes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your IP address with `geoip-lite`, and as you say, 8-bit characters don't seem to work. I have had great luck using [geoip](http://github.com/kuno/GeoIP), which not only handles wide characters, but it seems to have higher resolution, too. I suggest you try that out, if you can't fix this.

**UPDATE:** Using `geoip`. First you have to [download `GeoLiteCity.dat` from Maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity).

```
var City = require("geoip").City,
    city = new City(__dirname + "/GeoLiteCity.dat");

city.lookup("82.246.239.255", function(err, location) {
    console.log(location);
}
```

Gives me:

```
{ country_code: 'FR',
  country_code3: 'FRA',
  country_name: 'France',
  region: 'A9',
  city: 'Nîmes',
  latitude: 43.83330154418945,
  longitude: 4.349999904632568,
  continent_code: 'EU' }
```

Comment: i tried to download the database from the site and have put it into the lib/ directory but i keep getting:

------------------------
Exception: Error: Not valid city database
undefined
------------------------

can you fork my code https://github.com/nkhine/livestats and see if you can make it work?

Comment: That error means that it can find the file, I think (otherwise you would get "Error opening file" -- is it possible that you downloaded the file but didn't unzip it? The file from Maxmind is gzipped, so you need to gunzip it first!

Comment: Sorry @khinester I gave you the wrong link! [Here](http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz) is the file. You need to `gunzip` that file first. Also, remember to heed the Maxmind [license](http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/LICENSE.txt).

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the GeoIp database from MaxMind will give you results in UTF-8. I suspect that the reader of the console log isn't decoding it correctly though the correct character is present.

Can you open that JSON object with something that would recognize UTF-8?

Comment: i am trying to push this out to a web interface, here is the code https://github.com/nkhine/livestats